# Render data from/to Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

The goal is to render a json data, which is defined in _data/users.json, to javascript code.

I have a json file in [root folder]/_data/users.json

```
{
  "users"
  [{
    "username":"test",
    "password":"test"
  }]
}
```

And in my jquery, I have tried :

```
...
{% for user in site.data.users %}
  console.log({{ user.username }});
{% endfor %}
...
```

Which returns me a :

> Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token %

Anyone who has some ideas ?

Comment: Those liquid-tags look fine, do you have more code to show? Usually there's a missing {, } or % somewhere in the file.

Comment: Hi Scymex, in fact, the liquid tags are included in jquery, the codes are like this :

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
{% for user in site.data.users %}
  console.log({{ user.username }});
{% endfor %}
});

Comment: For now, I just want to display the data (in _data folder) from javascript in order to realise the checking operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your liquid tags will only render if you add empty front matter marks to your js file.

**js/script.js**

```
---
---

{% for user in site.data.users %}
  console.log({{ user.username }});
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit** : I just got it ! By reading your code at https://github.com/cui-bo/cui-bo.github.io

You just want to call your `_data/user.json` file from you javascript, but you cannot because you don't have a _site/_data folder generated.

It's because underscored or doted files and folders are not generated by default, except if you put them in the `include` array in `_config.yml`. eg :

```
include:
  - _data
  - ....
```

You can then call `_site/_data/user.json` with a regular ajax call.

`Note`: your authentication method is far far from secure.

Comment: Thank you David for your response ! I did this(following code), but it doesn't work.
`
---
---
$(document).ready(function(){
{% for user in site.data.users %}
  console.log({{ user.username }});
{% endfor %}
});
`
The error is :
`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Or does I missing something else ? @David

Comment: Google is your friend : You jquery file must be declared before the code that use jquery.

Comment: Does your js file is containing the desired datas ? You really don't need jquery to do a console.log. Just leave your script as it was in your question.

Comment: In fact, the goal of using _data folder and jquery to check username and password is in order not to show the password in pleintext.

Comment: This is another question. Does my answer helped you ?

Comment: You know David, if everyone can see my users.json, anthentication is just a "children's game" :) 
You are the best, not only because you solve the problem with the inlcude in _config.yml, but also your patience.
This is the best answer, but what a pity that I cannt give u +1 because I have a reputation < 15 :( dommage !